# Prevent developers from modifying Liferay Database structure

Tags: liferay

I am working in an environment that contain many Liferay Newbies along with experts, now I want to make some configuration to prevent any one from modifying the structure of the Liferay Database, i.e. one developer started a liferay 6.2 server while connecting to a Liferay 6.1 configuration database causing the database to get corrupted ... I know that I can't make LR users read-only because any change is reflected to the database, but I want to put some limitations to prevent a scenario like the above.... is any related configuration available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular permissions that are required for accessing Liferay's database are SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE. Only when you're developing new plugins you need CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, CREATE INDEX and similar DDL permissions *on the database you're developing on*. Just don't give them the full permissions.

Update routines (that run when you have 6.2 code running on 6.1 structures) will require the DDL permissions or fail. And, of course, you can also [remove / unconfigure the Upgrade routines](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#Upgrade).

Comment: So if I take the first approach, I will need to modify the privilege when any developer wants to deploy a plugin, right ?

Comment: And concerning the second approach, does it have any drawbacks ?

Comment: 1: If your *developers* deploy to *production*: Yes. Do they? An alternative: You can do the database update manually, it's just convenience what Servicebuilder does for you. 2: You'll deactivate the upgrade routines until you re-activate them. If (only) those are your problem, this might help you. But I'd tighten permissions on production database, so that no developer can readily access the database without going through several hoops. Give Liferay write-access but developers SELECT-only if they need to look at the database.